# Knockoutjs:bind multiple html elements with same viewModel's property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to bind single viewModel's property with two html elements but its not working. It's binding the model's property only to the first element.The reason for doing this is that I want to show a form with same data (both edit and read only views of form).
Kindly suggest if there is any better approach to solve this problem(to provide edit/readonly view for form easily) .

Following is what I wanted to do right now.

```
<span data-bind="text: name"/>
<input data-bind="value: name" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `span` isn't closed. You can't use `<span/>` because [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-span-element.html#the-span-element) is not one of the [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements). (Self-closing tags are only for elements that cannot contain anything, like `<br/>` or `<input/>`; you only need the `/` in them for XHTML, although it's *allowed* in HTML [it's just meaningless].) So since the `span` isn't closed, the browser has to guess what you meant the `span` to contain; when KO sets the span's contents, it wipes out everything the browser guessed was inside the span.

If you close the `span` correctly, it works:

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<input data-bind="value: name" />
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/udocem) | [source](http://jsbin.com/udocem/edit#html)